# Корутина не ждет в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Корутина почему то не ждет, хочу чтобы обьект появился, подождал 5 секунд и что то сделал (вывел в консоль), почему он не ждет?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerScenario : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Wait(5));
        Debug.Log("x");
    }

    IEnumerator Wait(float time)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Действия выполняемые после n секунд должны быть расположены после строчки yield return... Есть же документация, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Answer (score 0):

Изучите как работают корутины в документации Unity.
После прочтения данной статьи вы сами сможете ответить на свой вопрос.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html

Решение по вашему вопросу:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerScenario : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Wait(5));
    }

    IEnumerator Wait(float time)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
        Debug.Log("x");
    }
}
```